# How to create logic for 'users who view my profile'?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

It might be a noobish question but I'm not sure how to write this logic...
Lets say I have an app with users and profiles and I want to process a view that show all the users that seen my (the auth user) profile.

How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you keep your data who viewed your profile in database ?

Comment: Well you will need to log in the database when a user visits another users profile and can then read out that data. For more help you need to ask the question more specific and with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

Create a function in the user model that logs the visits, you need to fire this from the user controller whenever a user page is shown.

```
public function logPageView()
{
    DB::table('user_views')->insert(array(
        'user_id' => $this->id,
        'agent' => Request::server('HTTP_USER_AGENT'),
        'user' => Auth::check()?Auth::user()->username:null,
        'session' => Session::getId(),
        'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
        'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()
    ));
}
```

Create a `show_views` function in the user controller to show the logged views. The `groupBy` makes sure that only one visit is shown per session per day. You can remove or tweak that to suit your needs.

```
public function show_views($id)
{
    $views = DB::table('user_views')
        ->where('user_id', $id)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->groupBy('session', DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
        ->get();

    return View::make('user_views.show', [
        'views' => $views,
        'id' => $id
    ]);
}
```

At least this should get you going :)